# Exclude posts that belong to a specific custom taxonomy term even if it belong to another taxonomy term

Tags: wordpress, function

I would like to exclude posts that belong to a specific custom taxonomy term "for example id=37" (and childs) even if it belong to another(s) taxonomy term.

Here is my function :

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'films_query' );
function films_query( $query ) {
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && is_post_type_archive( 'films' ) ) {
      $taxquery = array(
          array(
            'taxonomy' => 'categorie_films',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => 37,
            'operator' => 'NOT IN',
            'include_children' => true,
          )
      );
      $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '-1' );
      $query->set( 'post_status', 'publish' );
      $query->set( 'orderby', 'title' );
      $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
    }
}
```

Any help appreciated.
Best.
Pierre

Comment: You're not actually setting the tax query

Comment: Oh thank you so much.
I think I'm tired...
I forgot :
$query->set( 'tax_query', $taxquery );
Now it works like a charm.